# How to tell if an instance of a parent class was created from an instance of a particular child

Tags: c#

I find it easier to ask this question through a code example.

```
class Parent {}
class Child : Parent {}
...
...
Child firstChild = new Child();
Child secondChild = new Child();
Parent firstParent = (Parent)firstChild;
Parent secondParent = (Parent)secondChild;
```

If I wasn't privy to the above assignments, how would I determine if `firstParent` was created from the instance `firstChild` without accessing/comparing their fields or properties?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, `firstParent` is not *created* (there is no "new" keyword being used) but *cast* from the `firstChild`:

```
Parent firstParent = (Parent)firstChild;
```

To test use `Object.ReferenceEquals` (i.e. `firstParent` and `firstChild` are just the same instance)

```
if (Object.ReferenceEquals(firstParent, firstChild)) { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

simple equality operator should work. if `Equals` method is not overridden.

```
Child firstChild = new Child();
Child secondChild = new Child();
Parent firstParent = (Parent) firstChild;
Parent secondParent = (Parent) secondChild;

Console.WriteLine(firstParent == firstChild); // true
Console.WriteLine(firstParent == secondChild); // false
```

Because the default equality method of objects is to check by reference

> The default implementation of Equals supports **reference equality for reference types**, and bitwise equality for value types. Reference equality means the object references that are compared refer to the same object. Bitwise equality means the objects that are compared have the same binary representation.